# save contact to android application using cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova

I have this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function saveContact(wtspNum) {
var myContact = navigator.contacts.create({"displayName": "AnyScan"});

    var name = new ContactName();
    name.givenName = "example";
    name.familyName = " ";
    contact.name = name;

    var phoneNumbers = [];
    phoneNumbers[0] = new ContactField('mobile', wtspNum);
    contact.phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers;

    contact.save();
    };

</script>

    </head>

    <body>
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("/app/conInfo.php",function(result){
    $.each(result, function(i, field){
    $("#contact").append("<a href='javascript:saveContact("+field.wtspNum+");'><img src='/im/wtsp.jpg'></a>");
    });
    });
    });
    </script>

    <div id="contactInfo" >
        <div id="contact"  ></div>
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

I want that when someone press the picture, it will call the saveContact function and save a number to the contact list of an android phone. Any help please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a php file in the server side that create a vcf card file then dowloaded to the cell phone.. I haven't find another way to do that